# Cannot proceed download in android app

Tags: android, download, powerpoint

I'm doing a download function in my android app. I'm downloading a `.pptx` here. Here is my code.

```
download.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Toast.makeText(DetailSeminarActivity.this, "Downloading slide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            /*
             * Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
             * Uri.parse(GdocLink)); startActivity(myIntent);
             */

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadSlidesLink);
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            browserIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                    "com.android.browser",
                    "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
            browserIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/html");
            browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

            Toast.makeText(DetailSeminarActivity.this,
                    "No application can handle this request, Please install a webbrowser",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(arg0.getContext(), SeminarActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
});
```

My previous device could download the document (Samsung S3) but my new device OnePlus one cannot download it. It skip to:

```
"No application can handle this request, Please install a webbrowser"
```

I tried to download and open same `.pptx` doc from gmail and it worked. How can I make this run?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think intent couldn't open the web browser. but, why it is working in some devices and do not in some devices? plz some one help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly set `com.android.browser` as the component to handle the intent. It is the package name of the old Android stock browser, that is no more installed in the newest devices. For this reason on Samsung S3 your code works, but it doesn't work on One Plus One. A quick fix could be to remove these lines:

```
browserIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
    "com.android.browser",
    "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
```

When you press the button an `IntentChooser` will open if you have more than one app that can handle the `Intent` otherwise the app opens directly.

Anyway I suggest to use the [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) to handle the download of a file:

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(uriString));
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

You can also register a receiver to know when a download completes:

```
registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            //Your code
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, Mattia Maestrini Do you know why I can't load google map in my OnePlus One device? Because the other devices can. Thanks :)

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question with so few details. I suggest you to open a new question and put much details as possible to let others to help you.

Comment: @ Mattia Maestrini , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730257/google-map-do-not-loading-in-oneplus-one?noredirect=1#comment55230218_33730257